# Page not getting refreshed after excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have a page where I am exporting a file to excel on a button click on selecting some parameters. the file is getting downloaded properly. but the only problem is the I have a listview in the same page which i rebind after exporting and it does not refresh. 
Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: do you use telarik listview or what  ?

Comment: no i am using normal asp listview control here